# Access variable from the block's scope inside a method call in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lambda, metaprogramming, proc

I am trying to create a minitest assertion that is similiar to Rails [`assert_difference`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/495722a95687e25114ae75608dd3107ac5d6611b/activesupport/lib/active_support/testing/assertions.rb#L63) however it checks for any differences not just a numeric one.

Here is my current implementation:

```
Minitest::Assertions.module_eval do

  def assert_changed(expression, &block)
    unless expression.respond_to?(:call)
      expression = lambda{ eval(expression, block.binding) }
    end
    old = expression.call
    block.call
    refute_equal old, expression.call
  end

end
```

Now in my test suite I call it by doing the following:

```
# this is working 
username = 'Jim'
assert_changed lambda{ username } do
  username = 'Bob'
end

# this is not working
username = 'Jim'
assert_changed 'username' do
  username = 'Bob'
end
```

The first call to `assert_changed` using a lambda (or a proc) works perfectly fine. The second call using a string with the variable name is not working.

When it hits this line: `expression = lambda{ eval(expression, block.binding) }`
I keep getting the error `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Proc into String`. Can someone please explain to me how to get this to work?

Note: I got the `eval(expression, block.binding)` idea from the Rails [`assert_difference`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/495722a95687e25114ae75608dd3107ac5d6611b/activesupport/lib/active_support/testing/assertions.rb#L63) method.

Comment: Although I don't see you doing it in your question, that sure looks like the error you get when you try to eval a captured block.

Comment: I guess this is happening because you redefined variable *expression* that you then use inside lambda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When it hits this line: `expression = lambda{ eval(expression, block.binding) }` I keep getting the error `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Proc into String`.

I'm reasonably sure that you do *not* get that error when hitting that line but rather when hitting this one:

```
old = expression.call
```

So, the exception is not triggered by the assignment, but rather later, when the `Proc` is `call`ed and the `eval` gets executed.

At this point, it will call the `Proc` stored in `expression`. The `Proc` stored in `expression` looks like this:

```
eval(expression, block.binding)
```

The first argument to [`Kernel#eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) must be something that is implicitly convertible to `String` (i.e. something that responds to [`to_str`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-to_str)), but it is a `Proc`. Ergo, you get a `TypeError`.

The easiest way to make this work would probably be to just rename the variable:

```
new_expression = expression
unless expression.respond_to?(:call)
  new_expression = lambda{ eval(expression, block.binding) }
end
old = new_expression.call
block.call
refute_equal old, new_expression.call
```

Personally, I would have probably written it more like this:

```
module Minitest::Assertions
  def assert_changed(expression, &block)
    new_expression = if expression.respond_to?(:call)
      expression
    else
      -> { block.binding.eval(expression) }
    end

    old = new_expression.()
    block.()

    refute_equal old, new_expression.()
  end
end
```

Without the (useless) [`Module#module_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-module_eval), and using the `call` operator syntax and `->` stabby lambda literal syntax.

Comment: Thank you that explains the issue quite well. It threw me for a loop when the error pointed back to the different line.